# websocketのコネクションがつながらず、javascriptコンソールエラーがデております。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

web-socketの勉強をしており、以下の記事を参考に実装をしておりました。
http://ithijikata.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/03/06/021948

実装と言っても、ソースをcloneして、動作を確認していました。

しかし、動作が上手くいかず、javascriptコンソールには以下のエラーがでておりました。

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

websocketのコネクションが上手くつながらなかったみたいです。

スタンドアローンモードみたいなやり方もありましたので試しました。

```
vi config/initializers/websocket_rails.rb
config.standalone = true
config.standalone_port = 3001


$ bundle exec rake websocket_rails:start_server
```

しかし、ダメでした。

原因がわからず、詰まっております。

ご共有頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: clone して、`bin/rails s`したらところ、正常に動きました。確認作業のどこかが誤っていると考えられます。どのような作業を行ったのか、正確に追記されると、回答できるかもしれません

Comment: 基本的には、clone して、bin/rails sしているだけです。

変更点といえば、config/initializers/websocket_rails.rbの内容に以下を追加しております。追加せずにも試しましたがダメでした。

+  config.standalone = true
+  config.standalone_port = 3001
+  config.redis_options = {driver: :ruby}
+  config.synchronize = false
+  config.redis_options = {:host => 'localhost', :port => '6379'}


尚、ruby 2.2.2p95の環境下で動かしております。
bundle install が上手く行かなかったため、bundle updateをした上で、インストールしました。
そのため、Gemfile.lockの内容が変わっております。
ここが一番の原因でしょうか・・・。

Comment: コンソールから実行する作業といえば、
rails s と rake websocket_rails:start_server だけです。

Comment: 今後も継続的にやっていきたいので、できれば、2.2.2の環境下で動かしたいなとは思ってますが、最悪、バージョンを落とそうとも思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[websocket-rails 0.7.0 thin 1.6.4 / Handshake times out](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/379) に回答がありました。

```
# Gemfile
gem 'faye-websocket', '0.10.0'
```

を追記し、bundle をアップデートしてください。

```
$ bundle update faye-websocket
```

サーバを起動すれば行けるはずです。

```
$ bin/rails s
```

`ruby 2.3.0` で試しました。

蛇足かもしれませんが、`ruby 2.2.2 を使っていて、bundleに失敗している`ということがわかれば、もう少し早く回答出来たと思うので、何かを質問される時は、できるだけ情報を提供することをオススメします。

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。私の環境下でも動作致しました。
> できるだけ情報を提供することをオススメします。
仰るとおりです。今回の経験で痛感致しました。今後は注意して質問しようと思います。

Comment: ちなみにもし宜しければ、お伺いしたいのですが、ruby 2.2.2 を使っていて、bundleに失敗していることから、faye-websocketに関するIssuがデていることを見つけるまでのプロセスを伺いたいです。今後、こういった問題に出会った時に、自己解決できるようになりたく。質問の内容からそれますが、宜しければお願い致します。

Comment: bundle に失敗した → ライブラリの問題の可能性が高い → エラーメッセージに `websocket-rails` を付けて検索 → 発見、という流れです。`websocket-rails WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response` で検索しました。もし問題に遭われたときは、`エラーメッセージで検索する`ことをされると、解決力が培われると思います。

Comment: 再度ありがとうございます。エラーメッセージで検索する癖をつけていきたいと思います。現状だと、エラーがでた際に焦ってしまい、トンチンカンな行動をとってしまいがちなので。

Answer (score 0):

Standalone-Server-Modeで実行する為にはredisのインストールと起動が別途必要になります。
https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/wiki/Standalone-Server-Mode

websocket_rails.rb設定例

```
    config.standalone = true
    config.standalone_port = 3001
    config.redis_options = {driver: :ruby}
    config.synchronize = false
    config.redis_options = {:host => 'localhost', :port => '6379'}
```

ここも参考になるかもしれません。
http://altarf.net/computer/rails/2502

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。websocket_rails.rb設定例に合わせて試してみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。redisに関しては、brewでインストールし、redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf で起動させております。それ以外で何か必要なことはないですよね？

他の回答者様からの内容を見ていて、気になった点は、自分がruby 2.2.2p95の環境下で動かしております点です。バージョンの違いが起因している問題なのかなと思ってきました。とはいえ、できれば、2.2.2の環境下で動かしたいなと思ってます。